# Does Grid.Children.Clear() remove controls from memory?

Tags: c#, wpf

I create controls from code and add them as children to a grid, and next I clear them, e.g.

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myGrid.Children.Add(myButton);
myGrid.Children.Clear();
```

Will the controls (the button in this example) be removed from memory or do I have to explicitly remove them?

Comment: As far as I know if you still have reference to an object it won't be garbage collected

Answer (score 3):

They will be eligible for garbage collection and eventually be removed from memory by the CLR/garbage collector without you having to do anything assuming that you don't have any other references to the controls somewhere in your application (which you don't if you simply create a control, add it to a `Panel` and then remove it).

Automatic memory management is one of the services that the CLR provides during the managed execution of a .NET/WPF application. You can read more about this on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=vs.110).aspx.